# Assembly to C conversion

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working on the following code...

```
CPUToBE16(uint16 x)
{
    #if  defined(__GNUC__) && (defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__))
        if (!__builtin_constant_p(x)) {
            int bits = 8;
            __asm__ ("rolw %%cl, %0"
                         : "=r" (x)
                         : "0" (x), "c" (bits));
            return x;
        }
    #endif
   return ((x >> 8) & 0x00ff) | ((x << 8) & 0xff00);
}
```

Could anyone explain what the code does if the value of x is 0x0800

Answer (score 0):

The C line is all you need to decipher, and those contents are standard C operators that you should be able to figure out on your own.

The assembly portion of this is inside a preprocessor conditional, which provides an optimized version of the function when certain conditions are met.  This version will produce the same results as the C version, so don't worry about it.

Also, the name of the function may help: "BE" refers to big-endian, and 16 refers to a 16-bit datatype.